# regExr pattern for get char between to special char

Tags: javascript, regex

for get `*created by:*` and `*M*` and don't get `*proudly *` or `* proudly*`(have space near `*` or `*` ) with regex in javascript.

```js
//not work
let c = "RegExr was *created by:* gskinner.com, and is *proudly *hosted by *M*edia Temple.";
const regExr = /(\*\*)([^\s|\*])+([^\s|\*])(\*\*)/g;
```

this work ( tnx for `@Wiktor Stribiżew` )

```
const regExr = /\*([^*]*[^*\s])\*/g;
```

but not working for : `* proudly*`

i changed to -> `/\*([^*\s]*[^*\s])\*/g`

but don't get -> `*created by:*`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pattern that you tried matches:

- `\*` Match `*`
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `[^*]*` Match 0+ times any char except `*` (So also match a space and therefore also match `* proudly*`)
  - `[^*\s]` Match a single char other than `*` or a whitespace char
- `)`  Close group
- `\*` Match `*`

---

To not get a space after the opening `*` or before the closing `*` you can start the match after the asterix with a char other than an asterix or whitespace char.

Then optionally repeat matching a space and again any char except an asterix or whitespace char to not match a space at the end.

```
\*([^\s*]+(?: [^\s*]+)*)\*
```

- `\*` Match `*`
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `[^\s*]+` Match 1+ times any char except a whitespace char or `*`
  - `(?: [^\s*]+)*` Optionally repeat matching a space (or use `\s+` to match 1+ whitespace chars) and 1+ times any char except `*` or a whitespace char
- `)` Close group 1
- `\*` Match `*`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/0FeG5z/2)